# Java 8 Filter Map<String,List<Employee>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, filtering

How to filter a `Map<String, List<Employee>>` using Java 8 Filter?

I have to filter only when any of employee in the list having a field value `Gender = "M"`.

Input: `Map<String,List<Employee>>`
Output: `Map<String,List<Employee>>`
Filter criteria: `Employee.genter = "M"`

Also i have to filter out the key in the output map (or filter map [new map we get after filter]) if the List<> is empty on the map value

Comment: Do you want to filter Map entries or just the Employees with gender `M` from each list?

Comment: input.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getGender().equals("M").......

Comment: Please add some more detail: What do you mean by filter (remove/keep the employees with/without M or remove/keep the lists that have at least one/only employees with/without M)? Can the original map be mofified? Is `map.values().forEach(list->list.removeIf(...))` not enough? It might help to add example input and output to clarify what you mean by filter. It would be even better if you added your own working code that you want to improve on.

Answer (score 6):

To filter out *entries* where a list contains an employee who is not of the `"M"` gender:

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> r2 = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(i -> i.getValue().stream().allMatch(e-> "M".equals(e.gender)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

---

To filter out *employees* who are not of the `"M"` gender:

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> r1 = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(i -> !i.getValue().isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
        i -> i.getValue().stream()
              .filter(e -> "M".equals(e.gender)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

---

To filter out *entries* where a list doesn't contain any `"M"` employee.

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> r3 = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(i -> i.getValue().stream().anyMatch(e -> "M".equals(e.gender)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

---

Let's have 2 entries in the map:

```
"1" -> ["M", "M", "M"]
"2" -> ["M", "F", "M"]
```

The results for them will be:

```
r1 = {1=[M, M, M], 2=[M, M]}
r2 = {1=[M, M, M]}
r3 = {1=[M, M, M], 2=[M, F, M]}
```

Comment: ha! how did I miss such an approach? what an idiot... plus one!

Comment: @Eugene, which one? :)  `allMatch`?

Comment: This is working friend.. Thanks a Lot.. I have to still understand filter/predicate/Collectors working mechanism

Comment: I need a small change in above example, i have to remove the key in the output (or filter map) if the List<> is empty on the map value

Comment: @Ranji which one of these three options did you choose?

Comment: I have choosed r1

Comment: @Ranji add  `.filter(i -> !i.getValue().isEmpty())`

Comment: thanks @AndrewTobilko , your answer is simple & helpful. Do you have blogs on Java topics.. I need to understand the working of these filter topic and also if any other also i can read out for my understanding.

Comment: @Ranji if it was helpful you might accept or upvote it :) I don't have a blog, but we can have a call or chat

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can convert a `Map.entrySet()` into a stream, follow by a `filter()` and `collect()` it. Example taken from [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples/).

```
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1, "linode.com");
    map.put(2, "heroku.com");

    //Map -> Stream -> Filter -> String
    String result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(x -> "something".equals(x.getValue()))
        .map(x->x.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

    //Map -> Stream -> Filter -> MAP
    Map<Integer, String> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getKey() == 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue()));

    // or like this
    Map<Integer, String> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getKey() == 3)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

And for your case it would look like this, because you also need to find out if there is a match in a `List` of object of class `Employee`.

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getValue().stream()
        .anyMatch(employee -> employee.Gender.equals("M")))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter only map entries that have only male Employes:

```
@Test
public void filterOnlyMales(){
        String gender = "M";
        Map<String, List<Employee>> maleEmployees = map.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 /*Filter only keys with male Employes*/
                 .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                                  .anyMatch(empl -> gender.equals(empl.getGender())))
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                          Map.Entry::getKey,
                          p -> filterMalesOnly(gender, p));

    }

private List<Employee> filterMalesOnly(String gender,
                                       Map.Entry<String, List<Employee>> p) {
    return p.getValue()
          .stream()
          .filter(empl -> gender.equals(empl.getGender()))
          .collect(
                  Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> result = yourMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(ent -> ent.getValue().stream().map(emp -> new SimpleEntry<>(ent.getKey(), emp)))
            .filter(ent -> "M".equalsIgnoreCase(ent.getValue().getGender()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the map entries if any Employee in the list of the entry has gender = `M`, use the following code:

```
    Map<String,List<Employee>> result = employeeMap.entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .filter(e -> e.getValue()
                                            .stream()
                                            .anyMatch(employee -> employee.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("M")))
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,Entry::getValue));
```

And, If you want to filter out all the Employees with gender `M` from each list, use the following code:

```
Map<String,List<Employee>> result = employeeMap.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                           e -> e.getValue().stream()
                           .filter(employee -> employee.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> result = originalMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(es -> es.getValue().stream().anyMatch(emp -> emp.getGender().equals("M")))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

Comment: same kind of code, i have tried,,but not worked. Always i am getting all the values

Answer (score 0):

Returning map of employee

```
public static Map<Integer, Employee> evaluatemapEmployee()
    {
        //return Dao.getselectedEmployee().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        //return Dao.getselectedEmployee().entrySet().stream().filter(emp->emp.getValue().getsalary()>8000).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        //return Dao.getselectedEmployee().entrySet().stream().filter(emp->emp.getValue().getEmpname().matches("om")).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        //return Dao.getselectedEmployee().entrySet().stream().filter(emp->emp.getValue().getEmpid()==103).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        return Dao.getselectedEmployee().entrySet().stream().filter(emp->emp.getValue().getEmpname().matches("kush")).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
```